# WCF sending incorrect http header "Transfer-encoding: chunked,chunked"

Tags: c#, wcf, http

We have some WCF streamed services which use a custom binding for gzip encoding. Our GZIP encoder is inspired by the Microsoft GZipMessageEncoder sample found there: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459

Here is our binding :

```
<binding name="GZipBinding" sendTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00">
    <gzipMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="textMessageEncoding">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="20000000" maxDepth="600" maxArrayLength="20000000" maxBytesPerRead="20000000"/>
    </gzipMessageEncoding>
    <httpTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="1048576" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="1048576"/>
</binding>
```

When calling these services with a POST query, the WCF client sets http header 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked', which is expected for a streamed service. Once in a while, however, this header gets an incorrect value: 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked,chunked'; the server then responds with an error '501: Not implemented'.

We never set this header explicitly in our code.

The only similar issue we have found online was encountered by salesforce.com: their OAuth service once sent the same incorrect header as ours. (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008mDUIAY) No word on how they fixed it.

Has anyone any idea what can cause such a behaviour and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: It could _possibly_ be relevant that that compression sample had some issues that were addressed in [Compressing messages in WCF part one – Fixing the GZipMessageEncoder bug](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmetzgar/2011/03/10/compressing-messages-in-wcf-part-one-fixing-the-gzipmessageencoder-bug/). I implemented a version of that article's code in a heavily-used Production site and never saw this issue (it says in that blog post "I’ve already reported this bug to the samples team and it should be cleared up in the next release.", but there never was another release..)